# curious about what CR and LF means

Tags: operating-system

I know that file line separaters are very different under certain operating systems, for windows it's CRLF, under linux is LF, and under MacOS is CR. But who on earth named those ascii characters? Are those (LF and CR etc.) abbreviation or something else? And dose every ascii character have a name like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CR stands for Carriage Return, LF stands for Line Feed. These names come from the age of typewriters. In order to start writing on the next line, you would push your carriage (the moving part of the typewriter) all the way back to the left, then engage the feed lever to pull the paper one line up.

And yes, other "control characters" have names like those too. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_characters

Answer (score 2):

`CR` stands for "carriage return", which means the returning of the typewriters head to the start of the line. `LF` is for "line feed" which advances the sheet of paper in the typewriter to the next line.

In most typewriters, `CR` and `LF` could be triggered by a single mechanism, but sometimes you also had an additional line feed key to quickly advance to the next line without moving the head (useful for formulars). And you could also omit the LF action on CR in order to write to a given line more than once.